# How do I add images on my laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-blade

I am trying to add images so I can see it on my views. I put the folder img inside the public folder and this is the code I am trying to see.

```
<?php $image  = public_path() . './img/logo.png'; // destination path ?>
<h1>Royal <img src="{{$image}}"> Dice</h1>
```

All I get is this error in the console: `Not allowed to load local resource`.

I am learning Laravel but I think that this should be easy to solve. Thank you everyone!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `public_path()` returns the internal absolute file system path, not the URL. To get the URL, try using [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls) instead: `url('/img/logo.png')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```php
<h1>Royal <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png' }}"> Dice</h1>
```

You can find more about the asset helper in the laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0):

wite like this `<h1>Royal <img src="{{ URL::to($image) }}"> Dice</h1>`
or

```
<h1>Royal <img src="{{ asset($image) }}"> Dice</h1>
```